# Accessibility Insights for Web seems not working with edge if internet explorer motor is used

Tags: accessibility-insights

I'm looking for Edge extension to test accessibility of professional web application. I have found Accessibility Insights for Web, and documentation said it works with Edge. I tried. If I run this extension with web application using chrome motor it works, however if I run it with a web application using Internet explorer motor "Fast past" loop and never give result.

Can I use Accessibility Insights for Web to test accessibility of web application running with I.E. motor, and if it's possible how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for using Accessibility Insights.

Unfortunately, Accessibility Insights for Web is unable to run in Edge Internet Explorer Mode. There are some features that are missing from Internet Explorer Mode, which prevents the web extension from injecting scripts in the page. If possible, please run Accessibility Insights for Web on your web application in Edge with Chromium.

Comment: Thanks to answer so quickly. Unfortunately, We have not choice, most of our web applications run only with I.E mode.ok, I must found another solution. Have a good day.